# How to override another javascripts css changes without being able to modify that file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm customising a Tumblr theme.

Tumblr's lightbox for Photosets is created through their own javascript, on the fly. IE: When i click on a link, the element is created at the bottom of the page. Here's a copy of that file: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/346800/stackoverflow-questions/tumblr.js and the line in question is #370:

```
            stage.style.backgroundColor = (image.className == "placeholder") ? ((navigator && navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) ? "#444" : "rgba(255,255,255,0.05)") : "transparent";
```

The question is, how do i make my css declarations take precedence over a JS generated group of elements? Since I can't manipulate their built in JS, I need to do it in my own file.

You can see that here: http://syndex.me
The very first post is a photoset.

Comment: there is a nsfw image at that syndex.me link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried creating your corresponding css rule and adding `!important` at the end?

Comment: Been coding after hours for 4 years and never yet used that. How amazingly simple! I've seen it often in other CSS but always thought it was for Explorer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could try the !important in the CSS

```
image.placeholder {
  background-color: #0000FF !important;
}
```